# How can i make the right most menu icon follow the horizontal scrolling in the navigation bar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, navigationbar

I am fairly new to reactjs and material-ui. The navigation bar is responsive it shrinks and expands if the screen changes but the problem is doesn't follow the horizontal scrolling. The menu button doesn't go to the rightmost corner. How can i solve the issue. Following are the [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfe0m.png)

```
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{
          width: "100%",
          position: "relative",
          backgroundColor: "black",
          padding: "0",
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "20% 20% 20% 20% 20%",
          gridTemplateRows: "auto",
        }}>
          <img src={AthuleBarImage} alt='Athule Logo Bar' />

          <IconButton
            id="basic-button"
            aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={styles.default}
            style={{
              gridColumn: "5/ span 1",
              justifySelf: "right",
              
            }}>
            <MenuIcon sx={{ color: "white",
                          gridColumnEnd: "auto",
                          justifySelf: "right", 
                          position: "relative"}} />
          </IconButton>

          <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={menuAnchor}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
              'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
            }}
          >
            {loggedIn ? (
              [(<MenuItem onClick={toProfile} key="profile">
                <AccountBoxIcon className={styles.dropdownIcon} />
                Profile
              </MenuItem>),
              (<MenuItem onClick={toChangePassword} key="password">
                <LockResetIcon className={styles.dropdownIcon} />
                Change Password
              </MenuItem>),
              (<MenuItem onClick={toLogout} key="logout">
                <LogoutIcon className={styles.dropdownIcon} />
                Logout
              </MenuItem>)]
            ) : (
              [(<MenuItem onClick={toLogout} key="login">
                <LoginIcon className={styles.dropdownIcon} />
                Login
              </MenuItem>)]
            )}
          </Menu>

        </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Check in the elements tab of the devtools.  I that component inside another element that has its width set to something other than auto?

Comment: Is it possible to create a sandbox showing the behavior?  There is something going on with your styling, but it is impossible to say exactly what without seeing the entire code.